# How to exclude "property methods" in Type.GetMethods?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, .net-4.0

I'm able to get the methods of a class using `System.Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)`.

However, the returned list will include "property methods", e.g. `get_PropertyX` and `set_PropertyX`.

How can we ensure that the returned list exclude "property methods"?

Comment: May the downvoter explain why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName);
```

Comment: `MethodInfo [] methods` would be better.that clearly states what type of variable is returned!!!

Comment: @Srinivas: First of all, it's not returning an array, so that would be erroneous. Secondly, I'm not going to go into the var-vs-Type debate, as it's purely subjective. Most C# programmers who look at this line will know that `methods` is something they can iterate over, and that's usually all we care about.

Comment: see this link  here...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx

Comment: Srinivas: Good article. I think this example falls under "Consider using var if the code emphasizes the semantic "business purpose" of the variable and downplays the "mechanical" details of its storage." The name of the variable tells us that it contains "methods," which tells us the business purpose of its contents. The likelihood that the consuming code cares whether this returns an array or anything else is pretty slim, so I chose to use `var`. But I would understand if someone chose to use `IEnumerable<MethodInfo>` instead. It's mostly a matter of style.